# Restful Application from HTML

Tags: html

Is something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="put">

</form>
```

or

```
<form action="/" method="delete">

</form>
```

possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification, only Get or Post are allowed:

From W3C: [The FORM element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

> method = get|post [CI]
>       This attribute specifies which HTTP method will be used to submit the form data set. Possible (case-insensitive) values are "get" (the default) and "post". See the section on form submission for usage information.
>
> ...
>
> For any other value of action or method, behavior is unspecified.
>
> User agents should render the response from the HTTP "get" and "post" transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [w3c recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1) you should only use post and/or put methods for form submission. Unless you are performing some kind of client side validation/submission.

Answer (score 0):

[No.](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_form.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML4 - no. GET and POST are the only HTTP methods allowed.

In HTML5, PUT and DELETE will be supported (probably).